# How to draw path between placemark

Tags: kml

I'm new on kml and do not find the way to create a paths between several placemark (each with some coordinate, a name, description). I checked kml tutos but did not find this.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Im not aware of any other way than creating LineString elements as in the following example http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml.html. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a LineString element with the same coordinates (Longitude, Latitude, Altitude) as your Points.

```
<Folder>
    <description>Frankie likes walking and stopping</description>
    <Placemark id="track1">
        <name>frankies path</name>
        <LineString>
            <coordinates>-46.67,-23.58,100 -46.754,-23.666,100 -46.6616,-23.5632,100 </coordinates>
        </LineString>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark>
        <name> 2012-05-31 17:23:09</name>
        <description> Stop TIME: 19:25:20 Source: network</description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-46.67,-23.58,100 </coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name> 2012-05-31 17:23:09</name>
        <description> Stop TIME: 03:01:59 Source: gps</description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-46.754,-23.666,100 </coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name> 2012-05-31 17:23:09</name>
        <description> Stop TIME: 02:26:13 Source: network</description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-46.6616,-23.5632,100 </coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
```